# Populate select list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to populate HTML select list using JavaScript. I believe I am doing it correctly, but I am not able to populate the list. The list is still empty. What am I missing  here?

HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/app/Base.js"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
    Select <select id = "MyList"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var select = document.getElementById("MyList");
    var options = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure your function is getting executed?

Comment: @Matthew I updated the source path and yes it is executing the JS function

Comment: Try changing `el.textContent = opt;` to `el.text = opt;` Option elements have a special `text` property that is different from the newer `textContent` property of other elements. Your browser might require that.

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean `window.onload` ?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Jr8N/

Comment: I see the dropdown list with 5 options when I expand and hover over options. But they are all null. I Dont see 1 through 5 numbers in the list just 5 empty slots

Comment: It looks ok here on Chrome.